# User Authentication for menu item action

Tags: cocoa

I have added an action for a menu item in my app. I have added an action using applescript. Now for that action to perform i want to add user authentication.  How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

See the [Authorization Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html). Pay very close attention to the methodology presented there - it's easy to authorize something you shouldn't, leading to escalated permissions for more than you intended.